# How to use NVL in PL/SQL for Date columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my first SP in Oracle.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEARCH(R1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                   UserID IN VARCHAR2,
                                   Name IN VARCHAR2,
                                   FromDate IN VARCHAR2,
                                   ToDate IN VARCHAR2
                                            )
                                             IS


BEGIN
           OPEN R1 FOR
           SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id = NVL( UserID, id )
           and ((LASTNAME =NVL(Name,LASTNAME)) OR( FIRSTNAME =NVL(Name, FIRSTNAME))) 
           and ( to_char(releaseddate, 'mm/dd/rrrr')  between FromDate and ToDate)
           order by RELEASEDDATE desc
           FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
END SEARCH;
```

In my table, I have columns Id, FirstName, LastName, and ReleasedDate. These columns are not dependent on each other. I used NVL to handle the Table columns, but RleasedDate column depends on FromDate and To date input parameters. I tried to use NVL, but I am facing issues. I am receiving the data in mm/dd/rrrr format. Is there any way that I use NVL for Releaseddate ?

Currently, I am receiving all the data from table where releaseddate is null and I am trying to avoid it.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
and ( to_char(releaseddate, 'mm/dd/rrrr')  between FromDate and ToDate)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve; if one of the procedure arguments is null then don't filter the related table column using that value? What if FromDate has a value but ToDate is null, or vice versa? (Using nvl for the names won't match if both the column value and the parameter are null, but that might not be an issue for you.) You also have a name clash with `id` - make the parameter names different to the column names, e.g. with a prefix; and why are the from/to parameters strings rather than dates?

Comment: @AlexPoole all the column are independent on each other. I just retrieve the data at least  if there is one not null input parameter. if the From date is null then I  use To date value. If the both From date and To date are null , I do not retrieve the data with releaseddate.

Comment: @AlexPoole I changed Id input parameter name and updated.

Comment: Aside from your other questions: If what you mean is that the arguments you receive, FromDate and ToDate, are **strings** (in whatever format), but the column releaseddate is **date** data type (as it should be!) then don't convert releaseddate to a string. Instead, convert the arguments FromDate and ToDate to dates, with the TO_DATE function. (BETTER: write the procedure to accept DATES for those two parameters; let the caller convert from strings to dates, it's not your procedure's job to do that for them.)

Comment: Other than the conversions between data types... Let's say everything has been converted to dates already. You want something like `(releaseddate >= FromDate or FromDate is null) AND (releaseddate <= ToDate or ToDate is null)`. No need for NVL.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for the suggestion. I will test SP with this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `nvl` for this, partly because it would exclude column values that are null. I would test explicitly for null arguments; something like:

```
OPEN R1 FOR
    SELECT * FROM USER
    WHERE (UserID IS NULL OR id = UserID)
    AND (Name IS NULL OR LASTNAME = Name OR FIRSTNAME = Name)
    AND (FromDate IS NULL OR releaseddate >= TO_DATE(FromDate, 'dd/mm/rrrr'))
    AND (ToDate IS NULL OR releaseddate <= TO_DATE(ToDate, 'dd/mm/rrrr'))
    ORDER BY RELEASEDDATE DESC
    FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

This compares the `releasedate` column values as a date, rather than converting it to a string; instead the string arguments are converted to dates to match the column data type, which is more efficient. It would be better to have the procedure arguments declared as dates, and make the caller provide a valid value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will test with this change.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to convert dates to character strings in order to compare them - you'll just get unexpected results. Instead, convert the character strings to dates.

As far as RELEASEDATE being NULL - I'd just use a condition to test for this. Assuming that you want to include the rows where RELEASEDATE is NULL I suggest:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEARCH(R1       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                   UserID   IN  VARCHAR2,
                                   Name     IN  VARCHAR2,
                                   FromDate IN  VARCHAR2,
                                   ToDate   IN  VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN R1 FOR
    SELECT *
      FROM USER
      WHERE id = NVL( UserID, id ) and
            ( LASTNAME  = NVL(Name, LASTNAME) OR
              FIRSTNAME = NVL(Name, FIRSTNAME) ) and
            ( REALEASEDDATE IS NULL OR
              REALEASEDDATE between TO_DATE(FromDate, 'mm/dd/rrrr')
                                and TO_DATE(ToDate, 'mm/dd/rrrr') )
           order by REALEASEDDATE desc
           FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
END SEARCH;
```